# ¿Cual es la mejor forma para tratar diferentes roles de usuario?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, autenticación, users-roles

necesito que me orientéis cual es la mejor manera para controlar varios tipos de usuarios, actualmente tengo 3 (Admin, user, redactor), el campo role lo tengo en la tabla users como entero (0,1,2), pueden aumentar el número de roles. 
¿Cual es la mejor o mas común forma de hacerlo?

He visto esta info en varios sitios

Controller

```
private function isAdmin(){
    if (Auth::user()->user == 1) return true;
    else return false;
}

public function admin(){
    if ($this->isAdmin()){
        return View('admin.admin');
    } else{
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@admin');
```

Vista

```
@if (Auth::check())
   @if (Auth::user()->user == 1)
       <li><a href="{{url('admin')}}">Panel de Administrador</a></li>
   @endif
   <li><a href="{{url('user')}}">{{Auth::user()->name}}</a></li>
   <li><a href="{{url('auth/logout')}}">Salir</a></li>
@else
   <li><a href="{{url('auth/login')}}">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
@endif
```

Pero esto solo es para administrador, ¿como podría adaptarlo para mas roles?, ¿que otra forma es correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Te valió la respuesta? ¿necesitas más información?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo, después de probar varios `ACL (Access Control List)` para `Laravel`, he seleccionado el siguiente: https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer

Aquí tienes un post con los dos mejores `ACL` de `Laravel` ( o al menos eso dice el autor) que te puede dar una idea de la diferencia de ambos: https://laravel-news.com/two-best-roles-permissions-packages

Yo he seleccionado `Bouncer` porque es el que más se adapta a mis necesidades, échale un vistazo y selecciona la que más te guste o más fácil te sea entender.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/72467)

Comment: El problema es que no le puedo dar ejemplos concretos puesto que ambos `ACL` funcionan de manera diferente, y tendrá que ser el quien decida seleccionar uno u otro, dependiendo de sus necesidades. Me gustaría poder ayudarle más, pero depende mucho de las necesidades concretas.